# How to send a reply sms on receiving a sms?

Tags: java, android, gps, sms, android-manifest

I have an application which requires sending sms from one user to another.On receiving this sms it sends back a reply sms.I have developed a code but the problem is it goes in aloop of sending again and again from one user to another.For example if user 1 sends some sms to user 2,then a sms is automatically sent to user 1 which in turn automatically sends sms to user 2 again and this goes again and again.How can I avoid that? I have to send the reply sms only once from user 2 to user 1 and then no return sms.Please help me with this code.

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/rt2Dd20k

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using special characters (data) to identify the reply sms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the exact text that the automated SMS reply will contain, can't you just put a condition around the block that sends the reply?

```
String autoReplyText = "Whats up";
boolean isAutoReply = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().equals(autoReplyText);

if (!isAutoReply) {
    sms.sendTextMessage(str2, null, autoReplyText, pi, null);
}
```

**edit:** if the message is dynamic (which it seems that it needs to be, based on your comments) then you could ensure that all automatic replies start with a special string token which identifies them as an automatic reply. This way, if you receive a message that starts with your token, you know you don't need to reply:

```
String autoReplyToken = "[BANANA]";
String autoReplyText = autoReplyToken + " dynamic message content";

boolean isAutoReply = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().startsWith(autoReplyToken);

if (!isAutoReply) {
    sms.sendTextMessage(str2, null, autoReplyText, pi, null);
}
```

Comment: The reply sms will contain the user's longitude and latitude which are send to the first user so that the first user  can get the location of second user.Right now I'm sending the sms from first user and this message must be replied by second user with second user's location.Now longitude and latitude can be obtained using gps and then sent as reply message to first user.Now can you give some hint how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I have two sims! Is it possible that i get to know which sim is receiving sms so that i can reply from the sim of of my choice?